# How can I cook chicken in a similar way to how it was done in Biblical times?

Tags: chicken, history, middle-eastern-cuisine, pre-columbian-cuisine

I want to make a historically accurate biblical meal for a group. I'm using chicken, and serving it with flatbread and an Israeli salad (sans tomatoes and other new world vegetables)

Does anyone have a recipe for a historical barbecue chicken or an idea of what sorts of spices were used back then?

edit: Just thought I'd let you guys know

I marinated the chicken in a mixture of rosemary, thyme, oregano, toasted sesame, garlic, salt and a bit of mint/pepper overnight. Then put them on skewers. Maybe not 100% authentic, but tasty.

Comment: Which biblical era are you interested in?

Comment: The real question - how rich were the people of the time you're trying to imitate?

Comment: "historical barbecue chicken" sounds like an oxymoron.

Comment: Take the chicken to the temple, Burn the fatty portions on the altar, and eat the rest.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[McCormick Science Institute: History of Spices:](http://www.mccormickscienceinstitute.com/content.cfm?ID=10498)

> Papyri from Ancient Egypt in 1555 BCE classified **coriander, fennel, juniper, cumin, garlic, and thyme** as health-promoting spices (3). Records from that time also note that laborers who constructed the Great Pyramid of Cheops consumed onion and garlic as a means to promote health.

The [Spice Encyclopedia at Spice Advice](http://www.spiceadvice.com/encyclopedia/index.html) appears to give history / origins for a large selection of spices.

Comment: Thanks, that spice encyclopedia looks good.
I know that spices were super expensive back then, but I want just a reasonable approximation. A real style meal would proabbly have all the meat boiled, which is not...good.

Answer (score 1):

Chicken, heat, oil, salt, honey if you feel a need for sweetness.  Spices were rare and expensive in biblical times, with even black pepper being used a commodity for gifts between nations.

Comment: Perhaps authentic but not much fun. Surely lemon would have been common as well as mediterranean herbs such as rosemary or oregano.

Comment: @Sobachatina probably not lemon; that's an asian plant, which wasn't introduced into west asia until after the biblical era cf https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemon#History

Comment: The honey would probably be date honey,  not what we call honey.